# how to redirect https://non www to https://www

Tags: iis

Hi I want to redirect our non www site with https:// schema to https://www. site.

I used below code

```
<rule name="Force HTTPS nonwww" enabled="true">
                <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
                <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
```

It works fine when I hit our site with http:// but when I hit our site with https:// it throws 404 error.

Basically when we hit http: or https: to our site it should  redirect to https://www.example.com.

I tested the above rule in IIS 7 and it tested successfully with both http:// and https:// but somehow it does not work with https://

Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
        </conditions>
```

This is saying 'dont do this for an incoming https request'.
Since both your rules have it set you never redirect https requests.
You need to be careful in general, you don't want to get into a infinite loop redirecting https://x => https://x, so you second rule should be left as-is

You can safely however change your first rule from:

```
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$" />
        </conditions>
```

to

```
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9-]+)$" />
        </conditions>
```

Comment: Thanks Tolan, I tried your suggestion but it still throws the same "host name  is invalid" error. I even removed the https input from second rule as well but it still throws the same error.

Answer (score 0):

We were able to resolved this issue. Since it was throwing invalid host error, it was not able to find the site name . Hence we created redirect site and using httpredirect, redirects it back to our https://www.example.com site.

This worked for us.

Thanks all for  your help.